# USB 3.0 not going past the speed of USB 2.0

Tags: linux, usb, external-hard-drive, fedora

I have a WD My Passport Ultra, which I know can reach 100MB/s easily while connected to USB 3.0 port, but I'm getting 40MB/s on 3.0 and 2.0 ports.

What may be the problem?
I run Fedora 18 (32 bit (on 64 bit processor)) on Lenovo G500

Will upgrading to 64 bit Fedora 21 solve this?

Comment: No' Upgrading to a 64-bit operating system will not solve the problem.  Have you tried another computer with USB 3.0 ports?  What color is the USB 3.0 port your connecting to?

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried connecting the disk to other computer - it's fine there. The port is blue.

Comment: Your using the [blue](http://www.wdc.com/global/images/products/mypassport_ultra/global/mypassport_ultra_11.jpg) cable correct?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, that's correct.

Comment: How do you measure the transfer speed exactly? I hope you're doing a `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/null` or something similar, not just copying a bunch of random files.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I was copying a single big file.

Comment: I have a related question if someone is interested in answering: [Maximizing speed of USB 2.0 clients on USB 3.0 hub](http://superuser.com/questions/1074183/maximizing-speed-of-usb-2-0-clients-on-usb-3-0-hub)

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors that can screw up your speed measurement:

1. Heavily fragmented file. This often happens to large files downloaded via bittorrent, but any file can potentially be fragmented.
2. UHCI driver or FS driver overhead.
   (I would watch closely is the CPU usage during the transfer: the speed may be limited by the rate at which your PC can accept data)
3. If you're copying your file to `/dev/null` there's no problem, otherwise you may be measuring the speed of the device you're copying the file to. A similar argument applies when you copy an existing file to your disk to measure write speed.